# Vertical and horizontal percolation on heterogeneous honeycomb lattice

Tags: pr.probability, statistical-physics, percolation

I have a regular honeycomb lattice where a bond in the unit cell aligns with $(1,0)$; call this the horizontal direction. Each horizontal bond in the lattice is open with probability $p$ and each "vertical" bond (the two remaining bonds in the unit cell) is open with probability $q$.

Given any bond, I would like to find expressions for (1) the probability that the bond is contained in any infinite connected component running horizontally and (2) the probability that the bond is contained in any infinite connected component running vertically.

I am not aware of any exact results for this or similar problems. Any pointers will be appreciated.